# AngularJS Upgrade Broke Custom Directive

Tags: angularjs

I just upgraded to angular version 1.2.1 from version 1.0.8 and my custom directive has stopped working.  This directive is supposed to format a date that's bound to a text input via ng-model.  Here's the directive and the HTML and here's a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgQ2LbRwynqMZ9jQu5tI?p=preview) that works in 1.0.8 but not 1.2.1:

```
      app.directive('uiDate', function ($filter, $parse) {
          return {
              require: 'ngModel',
              restrict: 'A',
              link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                  // THIS FUNCTION ISN'T FIRING IN 1.2.1
                  ngModel.$render = function () {
                      element.val('formatted date goes here');
                      //element.val(formatDate(ngModel.$modelValue));
                  };
              }
          };
      });

<input type="text" ng-model="crazyDate" ui-date />
```

If there is a better way to format a Microsoft-serialized date that looks like '/Date(1380600000000)/' into a text input bound with ng-model, I welcome your thoughts on better solutions, but using a custom directive is the only way I could figure it out as a new angular user.  Thanks for your help!

Andy

Comment: Have your tried to use `scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel)` instead of `ngModel.$render` I've heard of there being some issues with using `$render` in the way you are using it and having it execute on successive changes to ngModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your plunkr to a working one:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTWvnQkXOdVEM6j2ZKvT

Also, take a look at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ZJi_t9aYC-o

Comment: Thank you - it works well with scope.$watch as you and m.e.conroy have indicated